# Capturar valores de arrays para mostrarlo en un panelGrid (PrimeFaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, array

Hago un proyecto usando Serverfaces y Primefaces, y me encuentro ante esta situacion. Estoy imprimiendo las busquedas de mi pagina (de hoteles) en un dataGrid. A su vez, si selecciono cualquier hotel, este me imprime cierta informacion que quiero en un dialog, que contiene un panelGrid (ambos componentes son de Primefaces). Esta es mi clase donde cargo la informacion:

```
    package Clases;

public class ResultElement {
    private String nombre, imagen, localidad, id;
    private String tipoHabitacion[], alojamiento[], imagenCuarto[];
    private int personas[], disponible[];
    private String precio[];
    public ResultElement(String nombre, String imagen, String localidad,String id,
                         String tipoHabitacion[], String alojamiento[], String imagenCuarto[],
                         int personas[], int disponible[], String precio[]){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.imagen=imagen;
        this.localidad=localidad;
        this.id = id;
        this.tipoHabitacion = tipoHabitacion;
        this.alojamiento = alojamiento;
        this.imagenCuarto = imagenCuarto;
        this.personas = personas;
        this.disponible = disponible;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the imagen
     */
    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    /**
     * @param imagen the imagen to set
     */
    public void setImagen(String imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    /**
     * @return the localidad
     */
    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    /**
     * @param localidad the localidad to set
     */
    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tipoHabitacion
     */
    public String[] getTipoHabitacion() {
        return tipoHabitacion;
    }

    /**
     * @param tipoHabitacion the tipoHabitacion to set
     */
    public void setTipoHabitacion(String[] tipoHabitacion) {
        this.tipoHabitacion = tipoHabitacion;
    }

    /**
     * @return the alojamiento
     */
    public String[] getAlojamiento() {
        return alojamiento;
    }

    /**
     * @param alojamiento the alojamiento to set
     */
    public void setAlojamiento(String[] alojamiento) {
        this.alojamiento = alojamiento;
    }

    /**
     * @return the imagenCuarto
     */
    public String[] getImagenCuarto() {
        return imagenCuarto;
    }

    /**
     * @param imagenCuarto the imagenCuarto to set
     */
    public void setImagenCuarto(String[] imagenCuarto) {
        this.imagenCuarto = imagenCuarto;
    }

    /**
     * @return the personas
     */
    public int[] getPersonas() {
        return personas;
    }

    /**
     * @param personas the personas to set
     */
    public void setPersonas(int personas[]) {
        this.personas = personas;
    }

    /**
     * @return the disponible
     */
    public int[] getDisponible() {
        return disponible;
    }

    /**
     * @param disponible the disponible to set
     */
    public void setDisponible(int disponible[]) {
        this.disponible = disponible;
    }

    /**
     * @return the precio
     */
    public String[] getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    /**
     * @param precio the precio to set
     */
    public void setPrecio(String precio[]) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public void pruebaCuarto(){
        for(int i=0;i<3; i++){
            System.out.println(imagenCuarto[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Notese el ultimo metodo. Solo imprime las cadenas de las imagenes por consola ya. Esto sera clave para que puedan comprender mi problema. Cada objeto tiene 6 arreglos como atributo, y todos tendran siempre 3 como indice total.

Bien, quiero imprimir ahora esos datos en el panelGrid, pero sucede lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información de los detalles, siempre se repite para todos los hoteles. Es como si cargara la información de los detalles del ultimo hotel (el de la derecha) para todos los demás hoteles, y lo mas raro es que si compruebo por consola, la información se esta cargando bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resalte la ultima parte en rojo porque es la única información que me quiere mostrar mi pagina (la del ultimo hotel). Bueno, el código donde cargo todo es este:

```
   public void cargarPortada(){   
        try{
            int i = 0;
            String habitacion[] = new String[3];
            String alojamiento[] = new String[3];
            String imagen[] = new String[3];
            int prsonas[] = new int[3];
            int disponible[] = new int[3];
            String precio[] = new String[3];
            ResultSet rs = GestorDB.getConsulta("SELECT HOTELES.IDHOTELES, HOTELES.NOMBRE AS A, HOTELES.IMGHOTEL, LOCALIDADES.NOMBRE AS B FROM HOTELES INNER JOIN LOCALIDADES"
                + " ON LOCALIDADES.IDLOCALIDADES = HOTELES.LOCALIDADES_IDLOCALIDADES");
            ResultSet rp;
            while(rs.next()){
               i = 0;
               rp = GestorDB.getConsulta("SELECT TIPO_HABITACION, ALOJAMIENTO, IMGHAB, PERSONAS, N_DISPONIBLE, PRECIO_NOCHE"
                       + " FROM TARIFAS WHERE HOTELES_IDHOTELES='" + rs.getString("IDHOTELES") + "'");
                   while(rp.next()){
                         habitacion[i] = rp.getString("TIPO_HABITACION");
                         alojamiento[i] = rp.getString("ALOJAMIENTO");
                         imagen[i] = rp.getString("IMGHAB");
                         prsonas[i] = rp.getInt("PERSONAS");
                         disponible[i] = rp.getInt("N_DISPONIBLE");
                         precio[i] = rp.getString("PRECIO_NOCHE");
                         i++;
                    }
               ResultElement res = new ResultElement(rs.getString("A"), rs.getString("IMGHOTEL"),rs.getString("B"),rs.getString("IDHOTELES"),habitacion,
               alojamiento,imagen,prsonas,disponible,precio);
               res.pruebaCuarto(); //AQUI COMPRUEBO SI SE ESTA CARGANDO BIEN
               displayList.add(res);              
               for(int c = 0; i < 2; c++){
                   habitacion[c] = null; alojamiento[c] = null; imagen[c] = null;
                   prsonas[c] = 0; precio[c] = ""; disponible[c] = 0;
               }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Buscador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }
```

Leí por alguna parte que yo podia llamar la posicion de un array por PrimeFaces simplemente usando los corchetes "[]", y asi hice... es la forma en la que estoy 
llamando todo:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{buscador.cargarPortada()}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./templates/base.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form id="form2">
                    <p:dataGrid var="hotel" value="#{buscador.display}" columns="3" rows="9" paginator="true" id="hoteles" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
                        <p:panel header="#{hotel.nombre}" style="text-align:center;width: 230px;height:139px;">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%;">
                                <p:commandLink update=":form2:detalles" oncomplete="PF('hotDialog').show()" title="Ver detalles">
                                     <p:graphicImage name="images/#{hotel.imagen}" style="width: 160px; height: 70px;"/>
                                     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{hotel}" target="#{buscador.selectedResult}"/>
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <h:outputText value="#{hotel.localidad}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:dataGrid>

                    <p:dialog header="Detalles del Hotel" widgetVar="hotDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
                       <p:outputPanel id="detalles" style="text-align: center;">
                          <p:panelGrid columns="4" rendered="#{not empty buscador.selectedResult}" columnClasses="label,value">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:graphicImage name="images/#{buscador.selectedResult.imagen}" width="350" height="350"/>
                             </f:facet>
                             <h:outputText value="Nombre del Hotel: " style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;"/>
                             <h:outputText value=" "/><h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.nombre}"/><h:outputText value=" "/>
                             <h:outputText value="Localidad: " style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;"/>
                             <h:outputText value=" "/><h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.localidad}"/><h:outputText value=" "/>
                             <h:outputText value="Habitaciones: " style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;"/>
                             <p:graphicImage name="images/#{buscador.selectedResult.imagenCuarto[0]}" width="80" height="50" style="border:1px solid black;"/>
                             <p:graphicImage name="images/#{buscador.selectedResult.imagenCuarto[1]}" width="80" height="50" style="border:1px solid black;"/>
                             <p:graphicImage name="images/#{buscador.selectedResult.imagenCuarto[2]}" width="80" height="50" style="border:1px solid black;"/>
                             <h:outputText value="Tipo de Habitacion: " style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.tipoHabitacion[0]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.tipoHabitacion[1]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.tipoHabitacion[2]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="Alojamiento: " style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.alojamiento[0]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.alojamiento[1]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.alojamiento[2]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="Disponibles: " style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.disponible[0]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.disponible[1]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.disponible[2]}"/>
                             <h:outputText value="Precio por noche: " style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.precio[0]}$"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.precio[1]}$"/>
                             <h:outputText value="#{buscador.selectedResult.precio[2]}$"/>
                          </p:panelGrid>
                       </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:dialog>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>                      
        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

¿Qué podría ser...?

**ACTUALIZACION:** codigo completo del controller "buscador":

```
package Beans;

import Clases.ResultElement;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import Database.GestorDB;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author SEMINARIO
 */
@Named(value = "portada")
@ViewScoped
public class Buscador {
    private String fechaE, fechaS, localidad;
    private int personas;
    private List<ResultElement> displayList; 
    private ResultElement selectedResult;
    private GestorDB gestor;
    public Buscador() {displayList = new ArrayList<>();gestor = new GestorDB();}

    public String getFechaE() {return fechaE;}
    public void setFechaE(String fechaE) {this.fechaE = fechaE;}
    public String getFechaS() {return fechaS;}
    public void setFechaS(String fechaS) {this.fechaS = fechaS;}
    public String getLocalidad() {return localidad;}
    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {this.localidad = localidad;}
    public int getPersonas() {return personas;}
    public void setPersonas(int personas) {this.personas = personas;}
    public List<ResultElement> getDisplay() {return displayList;}
    public void setDisplay(ArrayList<ResultElement> listaResultado) {displayList = listaResultado;}  
    public ResultElement getSelectedResult(){return selectedResult;}
    public void setSelectedResult(ResultElement r){selectedResult = r;}
    public void agregarResultado(ResultElement resultado){displayList.add(resultado);}   
    public void limpiarResultados(){displayList.clear();}  

    public void cargarPortada(){   
        try{
            int i = 0;
            String habitacion[] = new String[3];
            String alojamiento[] = new String[3];
            String imagen[] = new String[3];
            int prsonas[] = new int[3];
            int disponible[] = new int[3];
            String precio[] = new String[3];
            ResultSet rs = gestor.getConsulta("SELECT HOTELES.IDHOTELES, HOTELES.NOMBRE AS A, HOTELES.IMGHOTEL, LOCALIDADES.NOMBRE AS B FROM HOTELES INNER JOIN LOCALIDADES"
                + " ON LOCALIDADES.IDLOCALIDADES = HOTELES.LOCALIDADES_IDLOCALIDADES");
            ResultSet rp;
            while(rs.next()){
               i = 0;
               rp = gestor.getConsulta("SELECT TIPO_HABITACION, ALOJAMIENTO, IMGHAB, PERSONAS, N_DISPONIBLE, PRECIO_NOCHE"
                       + " FROM TARIFAS WHERE HOTELES_IDHOTELES='" + rs.getString("IDHOTELES") + "'");
                   while(rp.next()){
                         habitacion[i] = rp.getString("TIPO_HABITACION");
                         alojamiento[i] = rp.getString("ALOJAMIENTO");
                         imagen[i] = rp.getString("IMGHAB");
                         prsonas[i] = rp.getInt("PERSONAS");
                         disponible[i] = rp.getInt("N_DISPONIBLE");
                         precio[i] = rp.getString("PRECIO_NOCHE");
                         i++;
                    }
               ResultElement res = new ResultElement(rs.getString("A"), rs.getString("IMGHOTEL"),rs.getString("B"),rs.getString("IDHOTELES"),habitacion,
               alojamiento,imagen,prsonas,disponible,precio);
               res.pruebaCuarto();
               displayList.add(res);              
               for(int c = 0; i < 2; c++){
                   habitacion[c] = null; alojamiento[c] = null; imagen[c] = null;
                   prsonas[c] = 0; precio[c] = ""; disponible[c] = 0;
               }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Buscador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Que es "selectedResult"? El hotel que seleccionas para ver detalle? Te aseguras de siempre setear selectedResult con el ultimo hotel que seleccionaste? Coloca el codigo completo de tu controller 'buscador', en el codigo que incluiste no se alcanza a ver en donde rellenas el array 'imagenCuarto'

Comment: Como uno puede asegurarse de que se este seteando con el ultimo hotel que se selecciona?. Y si, el selectedResult es para eso, para ver los detalles del hotel @MarcosMartínez

Comment: El hecho de que estés llamando todo por indices directos y el problema persista, indica que no es un problema en la impresión de los datos, sino que el problema esta en la lógica de llenado al extraer de la base de datos. Necesitas imprimir mas mensajes en esos while que van a base de datos o incluso debuggearlos. A mi me parece un error en la lógica del llenado, no un error de configuración o uso de primefaces

Comment: Como vas con la solucion a tu problema? @TwoDent

Comment: Estoy realizando otras funciones de la pagina, lastimosamente el proyecto no lo tengo en casa... a penas logre algun avance notifico @Lcop

Answer (score 0):

Yo optaria por usar Dialog Framework, para abstraer la funcionalidad de visualizacion de detalle de habitacion y que haga la busqueda con base al dato que le pase como parametro al RequestContext,  favoreciendo mas la organizacion y que el refresco de la vista del dialogo se force, lo cual me imagino que debe ser el problema, el dialogo que tienes posiblemente no esta refrescando su contenido y se queda con la primera busqueda, el ejemplo de uso de Dialog Framework es este:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/data.xhtml

Si definitivamente quiere seguir usando el setPropertyActionListener tal vez este post te sirva.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159967/is-it-possible-to-call-setpropertyactionlistener-before-actionlistener